# Why can not get the data item on the li onclick event?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lightning-components

Work on LWC. Why I can not get the data item on the li onclick event?

```
<template>
    <li role="presentation" key={item.key} class={itemClass} id="ms-list-item" data-id={item.key} data-name={item.value} onclick={onItemSelected}>
        <div id="listbox-option-unique-id-01"  class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small slds-media_center" role="option">
            <span class="slds-media__figure">
                <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:check" size="x-small" alternative-text="Selected" class="slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right--x-small"></lightning-icon>
            </span>

            <span class="slds-media__body">
                <span class="slds-truncate" title={item.value}>{item.value}</span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </li>
</template>
```

Js file

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';
export default class PickListItem extends LightningElement {
    @api item;

    constructor () {
        super();
    }
    connectedCallback () {
        this._item =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify (this.item));
    }
    get itemClass () {
        return 'slds-listbox__item ms-list-item' + (this.item.selected ? ' slds-is-selected' : '');
    }
    onItemSelected (event) {
        let temp=event.target.dataset.name
        console.log('onItemSelected:::',JSON.stringify(temp));
    }
}
```

Always get console output **onItemSelected::: undefined**

Comment: I don't think you can split the key inside the component and the for:each directive outside the component (e.g. in a parent component) the way you're going about it. This is likely the cause of any of a number of issues. This child component should not be aware of if it is being placed inside a for:each directive or not. You'll need to shuffle some of your code around.

Comment: Try changing `event.target` to `event.currentTarget`.

Answer (score 2):

We can retrieve the custom data attribute from an event using `dataset` property or `getAttribute()` method.
Let's assume the api property "item" has value

item =
{
"key" : "value"
};

`<li>` element contains `data-id={item.key}`,
for `<li>` element onclick method `onItemSelected()`

```
onItemSelected (event) {
    let temp=event.currentTarget.dataset.id
    console.log('onItemSelected:::',temp);
    let tempCopy=event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-id");
    console.log('onItemSelected:::',tempCopy);
}
```

this should give below highlighted value, from lwc playground
[image]